# Execute a timed command in a time command

Tags: php, cron

I am working with an php application where i need to check a database of users for whom has birthday today.
This i do through a cron job.

Now, when i get the users with birthday, i need to send them a SMS.
The SMS has an individual time associated which determins when the SMS should be send.
Lets say John and Peter has birthday today. Peter works from 01-09 so he should get the SMS at 01 and Peter works from 08-16 so he should get his SMS at 08.

I was thinking about dynamically creating the same amount of cron jbos which equals the people who has birthday on a given date. Those cron jobs would then send the SMS to the appropiate people this one time and thats it.

My question is, is there a smarter way to do this?
Secondly, if the cron job generation idea is good enough, is there a way to remove individual old cron jobs so i dont clug up the cron job list with old jobs which will never be run again?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're worried about creating too many cron jobs (not sure how many would be a problem on your system), then why not create just one cron job at the OS level? Then you can call your program every 10 minutes or so, and it can check if there are new people that need to be sent an SMS.

Comment: The "problem" is that the SMS could be set to 8.01 or 16.44 or whenever.
But i guess that i could call the program once every minut or set a 5 min interval restriction on. That might work, thanks!

Comment: @Rasmus If you set it to 1 minute, make sure that your code takes less than a minute and is not too CPU-intensive, because it will run on your server along with your httpd and everything else. I gave an example of 10 minutes because SMS messages don't always get sent exactly the minute you want them too, as I'm sure you'll find out. Besides, why would someone need to get reminded of someone's birthday exactly at 16.44? 16.40 or 16.50 will do just as well.

Answer (score 3):

If you would like to send messages to each person at a specific time using cronjobs then you would have to create a cronjob for each person. Very bad idea in my eyes as you could end up with over 1000 cronjobs!

You would be much better with a system that runs a cronjob every 5 minutes or so (however often you want), and this cronjob executes a PHP script to determine if there are any messages to send out at that time, or between now and the last cronjob.

Whilst this may mean your users could get their message up to 5 minutes late, it is unlikely because nobody I know starts work at 8:02, and therefore, if the cronjob is at 8:00, 8:05, 8:10 etc, you will almost always get the message sent right on time!

Comment: +1, very clear. It is better to have a cronjob calling an script that does a lot of things, rather than having a lot of crontab entries.

Comment: This was what i got around to after reading the first post. 
Thanks for the awnser :)